# want to show Image

Tags: python, image, pyqt5

**I am creating a project of python in pycharm and want to add an image in the window center. (PYQT5)
Please see my code and tell me where should I use the code so that image should be shown in the center (i will u derstamd if someone will not edit mg question and answer it).**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        pixmap = QPixmap("browser.png")
        self.showMaximized()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QApplication.setApplicationName('Online Explore')
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

**Please Help**

Comment: In the center of what? If you add any widget to that main window, where should that image appear?

Comment: center of pyqt5 window